# polyglossia used in LyX

Tags: lyx, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I am writing a Hebrew document that also contains in-line English text. For that, I am using `polyglossia` to facilitate multilingual typesetting.

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}
% \usepackage{bidi} % really needed?
\begin{document}
פונקציה מקבוצה 
\LRE{\textenglish{X}}
 לקבוצה 
\LRE{\textenglish{Y}}
 מסומנת $f:X\to Y$.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]
I want to be able to produce this scheme of LaTeX file with LyX's Export to LaTeX (XeTeX) tool.

I prefer achieving this goal with the LyX GUI, and not by writing the necessary commands in the Latex preamble found in the Documents settings.

At the moment the settings in LyX->Preferences->Language read the following:

[image: preferences window]

It looks like one has control over what command should be used to start an English environment. In this case it is `\selectlanguage{$$lang}`. But these settings rather produce the following environment when English is inserted in a separate line

```
\begin{english}%
⟨the English text⟩
\end{english}%
```

and the following when English is inserted as in-line:

```
\textenglish[variant=american]{the English text}
```

So, I have three questions:

1. Why is the `variant=american` option there for the inline English? I can't see anywhere in the settings where it is called.
2. Where the `\selectlanguage{$$lang}` has its effect?
3. I am looking at the exported pdf file, and the left-to-right and right-to-left issue is dealt fine, without surrounding `\textenglish{}` with `\LRE{⟨...⟩}`. Is there a real need for the `bidi` package here? If the answer is yes, then how do I instruct LyX to work with the `bidi` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad 1. `variant=american` is set in LyX' language definition file for English. This is also actually the default variant for `polyglossia` English.

Ad 2. Nowehere. This is only used with `babel`. With `polyglossia`, LyX always use `polyglossia`'s own language switching commands (the `<language>` environment)

Ad 3. No. `Polyglossia` automatically loads `bidi` (or `luabidi`) for RTL languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also have another question, please: What is the correct practice for inserting math formulas in such a document? Should I insert a `\begin{equation}..\end{equation}` inside a `english` environment, and insert the inline math (`$..$`) inside a `\textenglish{}` command? Or rather inserting the math formulas just as they are?

Comment: Or, at least, inside a `\LRE{}` command?

Comment: Explicit language or direction switch should not be necessary, as `bidi` redefines math in order to deal with that (at least in theory).

Comment: @tush I suggest you accept this answer (click on the green checkmark) if it answered your question so we can get it out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: @JSpitzm can you refer me where in the `bidi` (or `polyglossia`) documentation this claim of yours regarding the `\LRE{}` can be found?

Comment: It's not documented, but you can see it e.g. in the example in 1.13 in the 'bidi' manual. And of course you can just try it out and see that the direction is correct.